# Determine total Gas burned to-date

Tags: nearprotocol

I would like to be able to determine the total_supply excluding burnt gas and did not find the info via the Block RPC command. A couple of questions:

1. Is this / will this data be available or easily calculated?
2. Does the total_supply from the `block` method of RPC **exclude** burnt gas?

`http post https://rpc.mainnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 id=dontcare method=block params:='{"finality": "final"}'`

RESULT:

`"total_supply": "1001010266534987314249179942991989",` - Is burnt gas excluded from this total?

Answer (score 1):

No. Transaction fees that are burnt are deducted from the total supply. There is currently no easy way to get the purely inflationary part.